# setTimeout in React, not being able to clear

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have my code fire 3 seconds after the button being clicked. I can't manage to do this though. Either it is firing immediately or it fires and doesn't stop.

```
<Button onClick={setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(false), 4000), clearTimeout()}>Spin</Button>
```

It has been a long time since I've used `setTimeout` in any way, so it's probably a very simple fix.

Apologies if there is a similar question to this, I couldn't find anything that was relating to this enough to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an event handler (method) like an arrow function :

```
onClick={()=>{setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(false), 4000); clearTimeout()}}
```

or `onClick={someFunction}`

```
function someFunction(){
  setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(false), 4000); clearTimeout()
}
```